# The getter 'sundayIsSelected' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: sundayIsSelected

Tags: flutter

here I created a model, and try to use the model in the page, but I get an error:

```
The getter 'sundayIsSelected' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: sundayIsSelected
```

I set the sundayIsSelected in AlarmClock default value is false, why in the TimePickerPage there is still null? thanks!

Here is model code:

```
class AlarmClock {
  bool sundayIsSelected;

//I also tried followings:
//bool sundayIsSelected = false;

  AlarmClock({
    this.sundayIsSelected = false,
  });
}
```

here is my page code.

```
class TimePickerPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final AlarmClock alarmClock;

  const TimePickerPage({Key key, this.alarmClock}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TimePickerPageState createState() => _TimePickerPageState();
}

class _TimePickerPageState extends State<TimePickerPage> {

  bool sundayIsSelected;

@override
  void initState() {
    sundayIsSelected = widget.alarmClock.sundayIsSelected;
}
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Text(sundayIsSelected),
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you include how you are using `TimePickerPage`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible for `alarmClock` to be null, I will recommend adding required parameter on constructor and properly add others annotations.

```dart
class TimePickerPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final AlarmClock alarmClock;

  const TimePickerPage({Key? key, required this.alarmClock}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TimePickerPageState createState() => _TimePickerPageState();
}

class _TimePickerPageState extends State<TimePickerPage> {
  late bool sundayIsSelected;

  @override
  void initState() {
    sundayIsSelected = widget.alarmClock.sundayIsSelected;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(sundayIsSelected.toString());
  }
}
```

And use it like

```dart
final alarmClock = AlarmClock(),
....
TimePickerPage(
  alarmClock: alarmClock, 
),
// or 
TimePickerPage(
  alarmClock: AlarmClock(),
)
...
```

Find more on [docs.flutter.dev](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/widgets).

Comment: Hi Yeasin thx you for your reply, could you plz let me know, I set the sundayIsSelected in AlarmClock default value is false, why in the TimePickerPage it is still null?

Comment: you need to create an object then pass it  on `TimePickerPage`

Comment: Hi Yeasin, thx for ur answer, you are right